# How to stop particle from vibrating when still on a surface?

Tags: particles, collision

I created a scene where a plane emits balls that bounce off some objects and land on the ground.

Once the balls lose velocity and stay on the ground, it starts vibrating in its own spot.

How do I stop the balls from vibrating on the ground?

Ground settings (collision modifier active):
Stickiness - 0.5
Friction - 0.782

Answer (score 1):

Try *Damping* in the Ground Plane's *Physics Properties > Collision > Particle*:
[image]
Left: Damping = 1.0, Right: Damping = 0.0

Comment: Appreciate your reply! However, the particles are still vibrating on the ground. Is there another method I could try?

Comment: Set the ground's plane to kill particles and it worked. Thank you so much for your kind reply!